# Nativescript - referencing Android api methods

Tags: nativescript

I'm getting an syntax/undefined error in VSCode (under Android) for Manifest.

`android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Exact message is "Property 'Manifest' does not exist on type 'typeof android'.".

I don't have 'android' defined - but so doesn't the following sample

[sample file](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ImageUpload/blob/master/app/main-page.js)

My references.d.ts file looks like

`/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.es2016.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dashman you can provide string instead of the actual enumerations to use nativescript-permissions plugin.

```
permissions.requestPermission([
    "android.permission.INTERNET",
    "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
], "I need these permissions")
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log("Permissions granted!");
    })
    .catch(function () {
        console.log("No permissions - plan B time!");
    });
```

Note that I am passing an array of **strings**.

Comment: Ok thanks that works. Also in the sample code `platformModule.device.sdkVersion` is a string, and in TS, needs to be converted to a number first.